# Checking indexes were also restored... Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I made a backup of a whole PostgreSQL database that has indexes on several of its tables. I restored some of those tables using a cmd like:

```
pg_restore -h localhost -p 5432 -U jckusr -d mydb4test -t mytable2restore dbbackupdump.pgdmp
```

How can I be sure that the respective indexes were also restored? I did not exclude indexes during the backup process.

Comment: `\d mytable2restore` in psql should show any indices.

Comment: Found an interesting answer at:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123787/do-indexes-get-transferred-with-pg-restore